# Problem of determinant when $A^{-1}+B^{-1}=(A+B)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have two $4\times 4$ real matrices $A$ and $B$, and it is known that $A^{-1}+B^{-1}=(A+B)^{-1}$ ($A$, $B$ and $A+B$ are invertible). How can I prove that $\det (A)=\det (B)$?

Comment: It's not necessary that $A$ and $B$ are $4 \times 4$ matrices , It's true in general.

Comment: Special case of [IMC 2015 Day 1 Problem 1](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/index.php?year=2015&item=problems)

Answer (score 10):

If multiply both sides of $A^{-1}+B^{-1}=(A+B)^{-1}$ by $A+B$ on the left , then we have
$$AB^{-1} + BA^{-1}= -I$$
Now put $AB^{-1}=C$ then
$$C^{-1} =-(C+I)$$ And multiply both sides by $C$
 $$C+I=-C^2$$
Hence $$C^{-1}=C^2$$ $$(\det(C))^3=1$$ $$\det(C)=1$$ Thus $\det(A)=\det(B)$ .

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb R$ and $x^3=1$ then $x=1$ .

Comment: Yes, I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: If we would allow complex matrices, then we couldn't deduce this, as there are also two other (complex) solutions of $z^3=1$, correct? Is the statement false if we allow complex matrices?

Comment: @Roland Yes. If entries are complex number , then $\det(A) = \omega \det(B)$. where $\omega$ is a [third root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).